# Bootstrap Horizontal Form label along with a muted caption

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the following Bootstrap Horizontal form if I want to add a caption right below Order label as `<small class="text-muted">Must be at least 200</small>` where do I place it? **NOTE**: Question is related to how to place a muted caption in small muted font right underneath a Bootstrap horizontal form's label. I know the role of placeholder attribute but in actual app I do need to place such a caption underneath a form's label.

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Horizontal form</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put wrap the `<label>` with a new `div`, move the `col-sm-2` to that div and add the `small` element inside:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Horizontal form</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="control-label" for="email">Email:</label><br />
        <small class="text-muted">Must be at least 200</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="control-label" for="pwd">Password:</label><br />
        <small class="text-muted">Must be at least 200</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

> Open in **Full page** to see the actual result

Comment: It seems you are on the right track. I do need Horizontal form as shown in my snapshot. Yours is inline form.

Comment: Did you open this in full page? Once you run the snippet there is a link to "Full page". Click on it :)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for helping.